# Software solution for inter application communication

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to find the best way to communicate between multiple .NET WPF applications and share information between them. My Applications need to be able to start from one another and send large amounts of data between them quickly.

So far I have been working on using a gRPC service as part of my WPF .NET 5 application. This would then talk to the other WPF applications we have running on the same PC. I'm working on updating the older WPF application to use this. They are currently using named pipes and WCF.

What I want is one solution that will replace these as a way for them to communicate. Microsoft recommends gRPC as a replacement for WCF but I am just wondering if it is ideal for this use case.

Comment: What is "large amounts of data"? 1 MB, 50 MB, 1 GB, 3 GB, 20 GB? Per day, hour, minute, second? Is it always running on the same PC? Why have multiple applications in the first place? Why not put it all in one application so they share the same memory instead of sending data back and forth?

Comment: Does it need to work on Windows only? Or Linux as well? Are you looking for free software only or is paid ok? If paid, what price?